# Transforming intuitionistic propositional validities into validities of linear logic

Tags: logic, proof-theory, intuitionistic-logic, linear-logic

A tableaux method for linear logic is briefly discussed in

- https://www.academia.edu/6591354/TABLEAU_METHODS_FOR_SUBSTRUCTURAL_LOGICS?auto=download

D'Agostino writes (p.418-9):

> ''It is straightforward to translate the Linear Logic deductive policy into a stricter
>   criterion of use: a Linear proof is a Relevant proof in which each formula is used
>   exactly once. This suggests that a tableau method for Linear Logic can be easily
>   obtained from the relevant tableau method of the previous section by simply
>   imposing such a stricter use requirement. This conjecture has been shown to be
>   correct in [Meyer et al., 1995]. The reader can check that the tableau for the
>   Contraction axiom given in Figure 2, though being relevantly closed, is not closed. according to this stricter use requirement, since the formula-occurrence at node 4
>   is used twice. On the other hand, the tableau in Figure 3 is closed linearly, as well
>   as relevantly, since each formula-occurrence is used exactly once.''

I'm interested in proofs in linear logic with the sole connective ⊸. Basically contraction corresponds to using a premiss in the tableaux $\textit{more than once}$ and weakening in the tableaux corresponds to not using a premiss in a tableaux proof. So if I want to see whether a given proof of the implicational fragment of Intuitionistic logic is valid in the fragment of linear logic with the sole connective ⊸, I just check the tableaux to see if each line was used exactly only once to derive a further line.

However, I'm not sure how to apply D'Agostino's suggested method in practice when using, for example the tableaux system for the modal intuitionistic propositional logic discussed in

- Avellone, A and Ferrari, M [Almost duplication-free tableau calculi for propositional Lax logics](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Almost-Duplication-Free-Tableau-Calculi-for-Propos-Avellone-Ferrari/1205b56dec389e7c1b126d7e9bfd853dd4ab582e) (1996): pages 6-7

I'm not sure whether some of the rules they propose violate the ban against contraction and weakening in linear logic. For example, consider the rule

$$\frac{S, \textbf{T}(\bigcirc A \rightarrow B) }  {S, \hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{F}\bigcirc A, \hspace{0.2cm}  \textbf{T}(\bigcirc A \rightarrow B)|S, \hspace{0.2cm}  \textbf{T}B } \hspace{0.4cm}\textbf{T}_{\rightarrow\bigcirc} $$

This creates two branches: one on which $S, \hspace{0.2cm} \textbf{F}\bigcirc A, \hspace{0.2cm}  \textbf{T}(\bigcirc A \rightarrow B)$ hold and the other on which $S, \textbf{T}B$ holds. It seems to involve repetition of $\textbf{T}(\bigcirc A \rightarrow B)$. Is it therefore an instance of contraction and thus incorrect in linear logic (which bans contraction and weakening)?

$\textbf{QUESTION: Given the rules proposed by Avellone and Ferrari}$ 
$\textbf{specifically for the implicational fragment of the intuitionistic propositional}$
$\textbf{calculus with modality}$ $\bigcirc$, $\textbf{how can I check which rules don't flout the ban on contraction and weakening}$ 
$\textbf{that linear logic imposes?}$ 
$\textbf{Another way of putting my question would be this: which rules in the purely}$ 
$\textbf{implicational fragment of their intuitionistic modal logic, with the modality}$ $\bigcirc$ 
$\textbf{employed therein, would be unacceptable}$
$\textbf{in the purely implicational fragment of linear logic with the modality}$ $\bigcirc?$